# Bug: `watch &` won't work within a script

Tags: bash, bugs, watch

I had the following script to alert me when someone sends me mail:

```
cd /var/mail
watch -g ls && cat end
./alert
```

`end` would be a blank file; when I am going home, I would modify the `end` file from another shell, and the script would end due to the `-g` switch.

I then realized that, rather than opening another shell, I could simply tell the script the time I'm going home, and it would modify the `end` file by itself at that time.  When I do this and send `watch` into the background, the script terminates as expected.  However, the shell starts all kinds of weird behaviour after the script has exited.  Simplest buggy example:

```
( watch -g cat end ) &
sleep 2
echo y >> end
```

I thought I would use a different application to avoid this bug.  However, both `bash` and `konsole` seem to have this issue on my system (Debian).

I should add that running the above code directly from the command line does seem to work as expected.  Only yields this weird behaviour when run from within a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two processes writing to the screen at the same time can mess up. Try appending

```
reset
```

after `echo y`, it should reset the terminal back to normal. Maybe add a short sleep before it, too, so watch can't run after reset was run.

*Update:* If you aren't interested in the output of `watch`, just redirect both it stdout and stderr to nowhere:

```
( watch -g cat end >& /dev/null ) &
```

Then it won't clutter the screen and you won't need any reset.

Comment: But the `watch` is running in the background -- it shouldn't be writing to the screen in the first place...

Comment: Why do you think so? Background processes can still write to the screen if their stdout goes there. Check the update for a cleaner solution.

Comment: The reason I think so is because running it from the terminal doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Watch can still write some invisible ANSI sequences to output.